# Table.copy with variable to name the table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to copy a table using another variable as reference.

This is the table:

```
local tableofObjectTables = { }
tableofObjectTables["a"] = "aObjects"
tableofObjectTables["b"] = "bObjects"
tableofObjectTables["c"] = "cObjects"
tableofObjectTables["d"] = "dObjects"
```

This was my attempt:

```
local selectedLetter = "a"
local tabletoCopy1 = tableofObjectTables[selectedLetter]
     activeObjects = table.copy(tabletoCopy1)
```

tabletoCopy is "aObjects".  `ActiveObjects = table.copy(aObjects)` works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: If you put something in quotes it is a string? What about tableofObjectTables["a"] = aObjects? I don't know Corona though, don't know if it works. Maybe `aObjects` is null, where is it assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Assuming you declared **local** `aObjects`, `bObjects` and other tables above:

```
local tableofObjectTables = { }
-- store reference to objects table rather than string
tableofObjectTables["a"] = aObjects 
tableofObjectTables["b"] = bObjects 
--more declarations here
```

Now you attempt should work

**2)** If `aObjects`, `bObjects` are **global** tables you can use `_G` variable to access them

```
local tableNameToCopy = tableofObjectTables[selectedLetter]
activeObjects = table.copy(_G[tableNameToCopy])
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try code from [http://lua-users.org](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable)

**Shallow Copy**

This a simple, naive implementation. It only copies the top level value and its direct children; there is no handling of deeper children, metatables or special types such as userdata or coroutines. It is also susceptible to influence by the __pairs metamethod.

```
function shallowcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in pairs(orig) do
            copy[orig_key] = orig_value
        end
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end
```

**Deep Copy**

A deep copy copies all levels (or a specific subset of levels).
Here is a simple recursive implementation that additionally handles metatables and avoid the __pairs metamethod.

```
function deepcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in next, orig, nil do
            copy[deepcopy(orig_key)] = deepcopy(orig_value)
        end
        setmetatable(copy, deepcopy(getmetatable(orig)))
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end
```

Additionally, it is recursive which means it may overflow the stack for large tables.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't help. If I do shallowcopy(tableofObjectTables[selectedLetter]) then it returns the string aObject rather than copying the aObject table.